# Discretization of 1D Heat Equation with Temperature, Position Dependent Thermophysical Properties

Tags: mathematical-physics, computational-mathematics, heat-equation

I am attempting to create a finite difference solution for 1D Heat Diffusion through a composite wall with an abrupt material change and no thermal boundary resistance, assuming temperature- and position-dependent (due to material change) thermophysical properties. It should be noted that the two sides of the composite wall are held at a constant temperature.

The following differential equation is essentially what I need to discretize.
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left[T(x)\right] = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[\alpha \left[x,T(x)\right] \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[T(x)\right]\right]$$
Expanding thermal diffusivity $\alpha$ in terms of its subcomponents:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left[T(x)\right] = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[\frac{k \left[x, T(x)\right]}{\rho(x) \cdot c_{P}\left[x, T(x)\right]} \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[T(x)\right]\right]$$
This assumes that density is solely dependent on position, not temperature. I have interpolated functions for $c_P$ and $k$, and hence have an interpolated $\alpha$. These can be seen below.

[Density (rho)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ef8nG.png)
[Isobaric Specific Heat (c_P)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C9Zc.png)
[Thermal Conductivity (k)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0WsH.png)
[Thermal Diffusivity (alpha)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdkP0.png)

I'm a little confused about how I would discretize this. For the simpler, constant $\alpha$ case, we can discretize

$$\frac{\partial T}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left[\alpha \frac{\partial T}{\partial x} \right]$$

By bringing out the alpha and just doing a second discrete differential:

$$\frac{1}{\alpha}\frac{T_m^{p+1}-T_m^{p}}{\Delta t} = \frac{T_{m+1}^p+T_{m-1}^p-2T_m^p}{(\Delta x)^2}$$

Comment: Not quite sure how to put the LaTex formatted correctly. If someone could point me in the right direction, I'd be happy to do it. @ronno, thank you. Will do in the future.

Comment: Does it change materials at one point, or is there a transition region of some finite size?

Comment: Where there is an abrupt material change, it seems you’ll want to impose a boundary condition. My first reading of your question makes me think you’re trying to discretize across that region instead.

Comment: @Ian, there is an abrupt material change. @A rural reader. How would one impose that boundary condition if you do not know the intermediate temperature, etc? The two sides of the composite wall are held at a constant temperature.

Comment: If the two sides of the interface are held at constant temperature and the interface is infinitely thin then the subdomains don't even communicate with each other, instead all they see is their respective Dirichlet boundary condition.

Comment: Working with $T_t(t, x) = (\alpha(x, T(t,x))T_x(t,x))_x$, the right hand side expands to 
\begin{equation*}
 \alpha T_{xx} + (\alpha_x + \alpha_T T_x)T_x
\end{equation*}
Assuming $\alpha_x$ and $\alpha_T$ can be precomputed over the final range of $x$ and $T$, this suggests using central differences to discretize $T_{xx}$ and $T_x$. You don't get a linear system to solve.